# How to make LESS work if both css and less folders are not in the root?

Tags: css, netbeans, drupal, less, netbeans-8

So, I been practicing `less` and it was working fine until I created a new project in `drupal` and wanted to use `less` and `bootstrap`.  `Drupal` has a lot of folders and so my `css` and `less` folders were really `down down down` I mean, inside `themes` -> `mythemes` -> `another folder` -> `css` & `less` folders.

So, I decided to run a small test and yes! `less` wasn't working if I move the `css` and `less` folders inside another folder.

For example: this wouldn't work:

[image]

But this, will work:

[image]

I also tried to play around with this session by changing the `"${web.root}/files"` many times but it didn't work either:

[image]

Please help. I really want to use `NetBeans` for my project.

I'm using **NetBeans 8.1**

Answer (score 0):

Yes! I solved the issue.

So, I was typing the path in the `Compiler Options` by adding the `${web.root}/files` and this wasn't working.  So, the right way to do it is by typing the file names in the `Watch` section:

change `/less` and `/css` to `folder name/less` and `folder name/css`

Just like I did here:

[image]

And, in my `Drupal` project I added: `themes/mytheme/bootstrap_custom/less` & `themes/mytheme/bootstrap_custom/css`

I hope this help others!

NOTE:

**MAC users & NetBeans 8.1**